# I am using open telemetry for tracing,logging for my spring boot maven application.and i need tracing of api call and DB hit time

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, open-telemetry-java

I am using open telemetry for tracing,logging for my spring boot maven application.and i need tracing of api call and DB hit time
1.I need those traces in the application console itself(for my local testing)
2.Then i need to send those traces to collector running at remote linux host.
3.I want to export those traces to my own no-sql data source from the collector mentioned above.

Could you please help me on this.

I tried adding open-telemetry dependencies(opentelemetry-sdk,api) and I can see span created with some hash id...but i am not able to see DB hit tracing like how much time its taking to retrieve data from DB.And i added otel.exporter.otlp.traces.endpoint=[linux host details]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the [Spring Boot starter](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/automatic/spring-boot/)

Comment: thanks for the input Gregor..I am running my application in host1 and collector,jaeger is running on host2...how can i configure my application to send trace data to collector which is in host2..could you plz help

Comment: `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=host2` (see [docs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#otlp-exporter-span-metric-and-log-exporters))

Comment: thank you gregor.I am running open telemetry collector using collector cofig file in the host..and i just want to see the traces in the collector console itself..could u plz help

Comment: i export OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp and export OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http:host2:4317 but i could not see traces in my host otel collector console

Comment: i even tried open telemetry simple java example with java agent.but still could not able to send traces.https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/getting-started/ with export(below mentioned) but its printing metrics in java console but i could not able to see any traces in otel collector running at 4317
 export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:jarpath/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar" \
  OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp \  OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=logging \
  OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4317 \
  OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:4317 \
  OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=logging